# Assign vectors to each rows of a null matrix without for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, variable-assignment

Suppose I have a function `fun` in R, which can generate random output each time it runs.

I have defined a null matrix `M` with `r` rows and `m` columns. Note that the `fun` produces object of size m.

My goal is to assign randomly generated values from `fun` to each rows of `M`, **without using the `for` loop.**

I've tried something like this:

```
set.seed(200)

fun=function(mu)
{
  a=rnorm(2,mu,1)
  b=rexp(2,mu)
  return(list("A"=a,"B"=b))
}

M=matrix(0,nrow=10,ncol=2)
M[1:10,]=fun(5)$A
```

The output is as follows:

```
 [,1]     [,2]
 [1,] 5.084756 5.084756
 [2,] 5.226460 5.226460
 [3,] 5.084756 5.084756
 [4,] 5.226460 5.226460
 [5,] 5.084756 5.084756
 [6,] 5.226460 5.226460
 [7,] 5.084756 5.084756
 [8,] 5.226460 5.226460
 [9,] 5.084756 5.084756
[10,] 5.226460 5.226460
```

It seems that the values are repeated after every two rows. Can anyone help me to find an efficient way to do this without the `for` loop?

Comment: I am not clear on what you're trying to do. What is the ultimate goal here? Are you trying to populate a matrix with samples from a normal and exponential distribution? Or is that just an example? I don't understand where a `for` loop would come in. Perhaps adding your `for` loop implementation will help us understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: It is just an example. I'm actually trying to perform a monte carlo simulation based on the outputs from the function `fun`.  `fun` returns list as an output, that is why I've used a list in my demo code. So I need to assign random outputs from the `fun` for `nsim` times, where `nsim` will be the number of rows for the null matrix. Basically I need a matrix with `nsim` rows and `m` columns, where `m` is the length of the output produced by `fun`.

Comment: `help("replicate")`? Why is the function returning a list and not a vector?

Comment: @Roland Because my function contains multiple outputs. Forget about the list. Even if the function is returning vector, how can we address the problem without for loop?

Comment: If you want to call a function repeatedly, you need a loop. But I guess you are after a sugar function for this and for that see my previous comment.

Comment: E.g., `t(replicate(10, fun(5)$A))`.

Comment: @Roland rep() doesn’t call the function independently, it just repeats the one function output repeatedly

Comment: `replicate` not `rep`. Work on your reading comprehension.

Comment: @Roland pardon my mistake. replicate() works well, thanks to you. But my main problem was that `for` loop was taking too much time to run, but replacing this with replicate() still does not solve the time problem.

Comment: Then let your function sample all numbers at once with `a=rnorm(2 * 10, mu, 1)` and do `matrix(fun(5)$A, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
set.seed(200)

fun=function(mu)
{
  a=rnorm(10,mu,1)
  b=rexp(10,mu)
  return(list("A"=a,"B"=b))
}

M=matrix(0,nrow=10,ncol=2)
M[1:10,1]=fun(5)$A
M[1:10,2]=fun(5)$B
```

Comment: The problem was that you requested 2 numbers in rnorm to populate 10 rows in matrix!